# how to use the name of the file as a varible

Tags: php

I'm trying to use file's name as a variable and I'm also trying to use this variable to include the file using `include()`:

example:

file name is called: contact_us.php

```
$var = file name // (with underscores removed)
echo $var // will print contactus
```

Is there a way do that replacing `_` with an space and capitalizing the first letter?

I'm using this code below, but instead of having `index.php` I'm trying to insert a variable to replace the word `index`, is it possible?

```
<?php ob_start();
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'index.php');
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: `$var = ucfirst(str_replace(' ',_,'file name'))`

Comment: Don't. User input shouldn't end up in file operations without sufficient whitelisting. Use an `array()` map or `switch` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()` function like this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
$filename = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
$filename = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('.php','',$filename));
echo ucfirst($filename); //will print Contact us
```

To include the file you can do something like this:

```
ob_start();
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
$filename = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $filename);
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: but how do i call the current filename into a variable?

Comment: For that purpose you can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`

Answer (score 1):

The filename:

```
$var = 'contact_us.php';
```

Include "/document root goes here/contact_us.php":

```
ob_start();
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $var);
ob_end_clean();
```

Show as "Contact us":

```
$var = preg_replace('#\.php$#i', '', $var); // Drop .php extension
$var = str_replace('_', ' ', $var);         // Replace _ with spaces
$var = ucfirst($var);                       // Make first char uppercase
echo $var, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Contact us
```

Comment: looks perfect thank you, trying to do this withe varible so i dont have to type $var = "contact_us.php"........... : ::  $var = "echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])";